# ListView item does not invoke onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have `ListView` used custom `Adapter`. `ListView` item contains `TextView` and `ImageView`.
When i set up setOnclickListener on `ImageView`, `ListView` no longer invoke `onItemClick` for specified listener. It is ok. But if i set up `OnClickListener` of `ImageView` as null, `ListView` still does not invoke `onItemClick`. Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you try 'setFocusable(false)' on the 'ImageView'? If a 'ListView' row has focusable childs, it has troubles gaining focus or invoking click events

Comment: Yes I tried do this, did not help.

Comment: I think that ImageView fill to rowView, therefore onItemClick didn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you implement onClickListener for List Itemm child then List onItemClick no longer invoked So which ClickListener have to implement its depended on requirement Like :

1. When provide different action on List Item each child then implement each child onClickListener in Adapter
2. When provide single action on List Item use List onItemClick.

Comment: I have next situation. Depending on flag (bool variable, for clearly), one way I need to have two different actions one for item (not including ImageView) and one for ImageView. another way I need to have only one action for whole item in list..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your  `TextView` and `ImageView` :

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

To make sure the items dont gain focus so the `ListView` should be clickable.

Comment: focusableInTouchMode and focusable uses for another purpose. It is only focus, nothing else. If i need view to get focus, and if i need view to get focus by user touch. As I think.

Comment: @busylee from my experience, wrong focus on an item in your row make the entire row cant be clicked